# Python selenium is returning an empty list instead of elements

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to click some buttons that are generated with javascript but when I run my code it only returns an empty list, I have a for loop to click each button returned from each loop of the while loop because when it scrolls to the bottom of the page where the last button is, it should generate more buttons.

```
def click_follow_buttons(driver):
    current_count = 0
    while current_count <= 7:
        follow_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("user-actions-follow-buttonjs-follow-btnfollow-buttonbtnsmallsmall-follow-btn")
        print follow_buttons
        for button in range(0,len(follow_buttons)):
            if button.is_displayed():
                button.click()
        current_count += 1
```

my output

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

When I loaded my pickled cookies I removed some of the google cookies because they wouldn't add to my driver even when I re-directed to google's  domain.

Comment: That is a pretty huge classname for CSS, is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: @xbirkettx Yeah that's supposed to be like that, it had some whitespace in also.

Comment: Classes does not support white space in their name. Because white space is used to separate 2 classes.

Comment: if you provide an example url you're trying to do this for, we might be able to replicate and/or answer?